# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы в списке?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Имеется список, который заносится в гугл таблицу. Но в списке каждый десятый элемент повторяется, а именно: Коронавирус в России, затем также повторяется описание, ссылка, число подписчиков, дата последней публикации. В таблицу добавляется по 6 данных из списка. Затем с 7 по 12, затем с 13 по 18 и т.д. Подскажите, как одинаковые каналы удалить из списка? Например если с 1 по 6 элементы совпадают с 7 по 12, то удалить с 7 по 12. Если название повторяются, удалить все следующие 5 элементов и 1 предыдущий (предыдущий - номер столбца, следующие 5 - данные об этом канале)

Вот код добавления в таблицу каждые 6 элементов (данные о каждом канале хранятся в 6 элемнетах, номер столбца, название, описание, ссылка, кол-во подписчиков, дата последней публикации. Если название повторяется в списке, то эти 6 данных удалить.

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 6
for iop in range(20):
    insertRow = result[count1:count2]
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 2)
    count1 += 6
    count2 += 6
```

Сам список:

```
result = [20, 'Коронавирус в России: оперативная информация', 'Сообщения информационных агентств о коронавирусе в России.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd68d12f0-68e2-4c62-9337-4d733f1b10ac', '485044', '15.06.2020', 19, 'Fomag.ru', 'Про рубль, доллар, нефть, золото, сбережения, акции, облигации, брокеров, биржи, трейдеров, финансистов. Через нас можно обратиться в ЦБ, Минфин, узнать информацию от брокеров и управляющих компаний', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F8ad0f225-6c1c-45c7-ae7b-e212f3982362', '4032', '15.06.2020', 18, '«Собака.ru»', 'Журнал о людях, культуре, моде, трендах в Петербурге', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd06d1586-2721-4478-886f-96d7b0060c9b', '3071', '15.06.2020', 17, 'RT на русском', 'Новости телеканала RT на русском языке —https://russian.rt.com', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F2%2F2f9b5d62-9cea-4f45-8612-c67b634c801e', '11533', '15.06.2020', 16, 'Наука AB-NEWS', 'Новости науки, техники и технологии со всего мира', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F2569b8b5-95c4-4742-92ea-c30396bc55bb', '110', '15.06.2020', 15, 'Себестоимость', 'Узнай реальную цену всего самого интересного из того, что существует на нашей планете!Себестоимость IPhone 11 PRO MAX?Какая зарплата у Путина?Сколько стоит полет в космос?', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F58288829-818b-4a31-b9a8-74b1139b6e96', '144', '15.06.2020', 14, 'Белоручка', 'Политика и юмор.Пишу книги -https://ridero.ru/books/beloruchka/', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fbdcf32d7-926e-4b34-9769-c85d52d87d77', '148', '15.06.2020', 13, 'АНИМЕ', 'Привет Семпай! Тут про аниме. Топы, Арты, Манга (короткое).', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Ff5efdcb6-08de-4d9b-828e-8a1313c0fea9', '251', '15.06.2020', 12, 'Библиотека', 'Канал о литературе: для тех, кто вечно не знает что почитать.Наш канал в Telegramwww.tele.click/thebestlibraryНаш канал в Instagramwww.instagram.com/thebestlibrary', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fa9ed0885-c644-462f-b6d7-40b1454f27eb', '183', '15.06.2020', 11, 'Анекдоты', 'Самые смешные анекдоты собраны здесь.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F91486589-4370-4828-ad87-f752876cb86d', '439', '15.06.2020', 10, 'Коронавирус в России: оперативная информация', 'Сообщения информационных агентств о коронавирусе в России.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd68d12f0-68e2-4c62-9337-4d733f1b10ac', '485044', '15.06.2020', 9, 'Super.ru', 'Актуальные новости шоу-бизнеса', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F023c4d5a-0646-4909-80df-99580051a235', '5558', '15.06.2020', 8, 'Чемпионат', 'Ведущий сайт Рунета о спорте.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F28d368e0-8f4e-405f-b80d-623bf2183404', '5503', '15.06.2020', 7, 'Редакция', 'Канал Ютьюб-проекта Алексея Пивоварова «Редакция». Подписывайтесь!Ютьюб-канал «Редакция»:https://www.youtube.com/c/РедакцияИнстаграм Пивоварова:https://www.instagram.com/pivo_varov/Сотрудничество:info@redakciya.com', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F025f5b03-f65d-48a5-8a1e-7bc86978a6d0', '2111', '14.06.2020', 6, 'Один день в истории', 'Чем запомнился сегодняшний день в истории', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F79679054-938f-45e3-a092-5e5971b15e50', '310', '15.06.2020', 5, 'Халява, Сэр!', 'Бесплатные подписки на самые популярные сервисы!', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F3e7200db-58d9-4b7d-b440-6f683a3c489c', '8706', '15.06.2020', 4, 'Самый богатый человек в Вавилоне.', 'Книги, статьи, цитаты и просто умные мысли.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F57bd7559-d1a9-40d5-9884-1579e421c858', '54', '15.06.2020', 3, 'Словарь | Испанский язык (Español)', 'Изучай испанский язык и расширяй свой словарный запас.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fed72fe60-df92-4759-9afb-c0a6ec1c9460', '62', '14.06.2020', 2, 'Цитаты', 'Афоризмы, цитаты, поговорки все самое лучшее для вас. Мудрость народов!', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F998b7dd1-151d-4d05-832f-575e1c9ef901', '176', '06.2020', 1, 'Природа | Путешествия', 'Открой для себя Мир!', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fa2c14e03-3f97-4def-8cb9-dd9ea768513b', '68', '06.2020']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычный подход для получения уникальной коллекции предметов заключается в использовании `set`. Наборы - это неупорядоченные наборы отдельных объектов. Чтобы создать набор из любого итератора, вы можете просто передать его встроенной `set()` функции. Если позже вам снова понадобится реальный список, вы можете аналогичным образом передать набор в `list()` функцию.

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(set(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(set(t) - set(s))
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

Если порядок важен для вас, вам придется использовать другой механизм. Очень распространенным решением для этого является `OrderedDict` сохранение порядка ключей во время вставки:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Начиная с Python 3.7, встроенный словарь гарантированно поддерживает порядок вставки, так что вы также можете использовать его напрямую, если вы используете Python 3.7 или новее (или CPython 3.6):

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Обратите внимание, что это может привести к определенным накладным расходам: сначала создать словарь, а затем создать из него список. Если вам на самом деле не нужно сохранять порядок, вам часто лучше использовать набор, особенно потому, что он дает вам гораздо больше операций для работы.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390/12785139)

Так же вы можете использовать формулу `=UNIQUE(A2:B17)` или `Данные - Удалить Дубликаты` в самой таблице Google Spreadsheet